# Deleting punctuation from a large text file (TASK: counting words, deleting common words, deleting punctuation)

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to programming.
I need some help to understand the code for removing punctuation from a large text file.
I came across few solutions and tried to code as per below:

```
import string

fname = input("Enter file name: ")
# if len(fname) < 1: fname = "98-0.txt" # Can Enter without typing, but not working 
# on shell
fh = open(fname)

# 1. Read in each word from the file,
    # 1a. Making it lower case
    # 1b. Removing punctuation. (Optionally, skip common words).
    # 1c. For each remaining word, add the word to the data structure or
    # update your count for the word
counts = dict()
for line in fh:
    line = line.strip() # 1
    line = line.lower() # 1a.
    line = line.split()
    # print(string.punctuation) # Provides all the different punctuations that might 
    # exist in a text
    print(line.translate(line.maketrans(" ", " ", string.punctuation)))
    # print(words)
```

But, I am getting a Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wcloud.py", line 29, in <module>
    print(line.translate(line.maketrans(" ", " ", string.punctuation)))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'translate'
```

I tried to update Atom with the latest python (I hope I did it correct.. I'm not sure).

Comment: ```line = line.split()```. ```.split``` returns a list of splitted substrings

Comment: Where did you get the method "translate" from?

Comment: You can also use **regular expressions** to get rid of punctuation

Comment: @neuhaus I searched for solutions for getting rid of punctuations online and found the translate and maketrans methods. This is new to me and I haven't used these methods before.

Comment: @neuhaus could you please guide me in removing punctuations with RE ?

Comment: @Sujay Yes, I understand your comment further after reading the explanation below from -gimix.

Answer (score 0):

As it has already been noted, `line = line.split()` transforms your original string in a list of strings - i.e. splits your line in words. So, since `translate` and `maketrans` are *string* methods you will need to either loop on the items of the list:

```
for word in line:
    word.translate(word.maketrans(" ", " ", string.punctuation))
```

or, better, remove punctuation *before* splitting the line:

```
line.translate(line.maketrans(" ", " ", string.punctuation))
line = line.split()
```

In the latter case you will still need to loop on the words in line to add them to `count`. Or, you may have a look to `collections.Counter`, that can do the job for you :)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! @gimix
I realised the problem was zsh shell because it uses the default Python 2.7 version.

Comment: Because when I tried the code in PyCharm it worked! I still need some help with that.. I'll need to sort out Python interpreter in PyCharm, and zsh shell and try the codes again. Is XCode needed for zsh update for Python3 ?